# Use Ansible to create Azure vm with UNmanaged disk?

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-cli

I'm just getting started with Ansible.  I've made simple vms before using azure cli and that worked.

There's an option/flag, --use-unmanaged-disk.  I've been googling like mad, but I can't see a similar option for use in an Ansible Playbook.  This is the guide I've been trying:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/sl-si/azure/virtual-machines/linux/ansible-create-complete-vm]

If I'm missing any info, please let me know.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- name: Create a VM with OS and multiple data storage accounts
  azure_rm_virtualmachine:
    resource_group: Testing
    name: testvm001
    vm_size: Standard_DS1_v2
    admin_username: adminUser
    ssh_password_enabled: false
    ssh_public_keys:
    - path: /home/adminUser/.ssh/authorized_keys
      key_data: < insert yor ssh public key here... >
    network_interfaces: testvm001
    storage_container: osdisk
    storage_blob: osdisk.vhd
    image:
    offer: CoreOS
    publisher: CoreOS
    sku: Stable
    version: latest
    data_disks:
    - lun: 0
      disk_size_gb: 64
      storage_container_name: datadisk1
      storage_blob_name: datadisk1.vhd
    - lun: 1
      disk_size_gb: 128
      storage_container_name: datadisk2
      storage_blob_name: datadisk2.vhd
```

reference: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/azure_rm_virtualmachine_module.html#azure-rm-virtualmachine

Comment: Are you saying that it's not declared specifically, and that just by specifying storage_container: osdisk and storage_blob that it's inferred?

Comment: yes, because you dont need storage account for vm if you use managed disks